Strange behavior of bash (overflow of argument passed to an executable)
I am doing a script in bash that aims to run some test for one of my project, and I faced a strange behavior.
In my code, I have a function test_it that takes $info: an info to output, $type: a type of test, $files: a list of file name, $options: args passed at each iteration to "./prog", $optdesc: a string describing the options, and $precond: an array of string describing a precondition for each file in $files.
#!/bin/sh


test_it() {
    info=$1
    type=$2
    files=$3
    options=$4
    optdesc=$5
    precond=$6

   for idx in ${!files[@]}
   do          
       filename="log/$type/$filed-$optdesc.log"
       if [[ ! -f $filename ]]; then     
            touch $filename
       fi        
       if [[  "${options[@]}" = "" ]] 
       then 
          ./prog $file  -precondition "${precond[idx]}"  > $filename
       else 
          ./prog $file "${options[@]}" -precondition  "${precond[idx]}" > $filename
       fi
   done
 }

I ran it first with this setting
## termination (CFG) with default setting:
## -domain boxes
## -joinbwd 2

type="termination"
info="info1"
files=("tests/termination/boolean.c"
       "tests/termination/cacm2009a.c"
       "tests/termination/cav2006.c"
       "tests/termination/example1.c"
       "tests/termination/example2a.c"
       "tests/termination/tacas2013a.c" )
precond=("${files[@]/*/"true"}")
options=("-ctl-cfg" "AF{exit: true}")
optdesc="termCFG"

test_it "$info" $type $files $options $optdesc $precond

Here everything went well. Then I ran the second test suit.
## conditional termination
type="termination"
info="info2"
files=( "tests/termination/example7.c"
        "tests/termination/sas2014a.c"
        "tests/termination/sas2014c.c" 
        "tests/termination/tap2008a.c"
        "tests/termination/tap2008b.c"
        "tests/termination/tap2008c.c"
        "tests/termination/tap2008d.c"
        "tests/termination/tap2008e.c"
        "tests/termination/widening3.c")
        
precond=( "x > 6"
          "r <= 0"
          "x < 0"
          "x < 25 || x > 30" 
          "x <= 30 && x >= 0 || x > 35 || x < -5"
          "x < 30"
          "x <= 0"
          "x <= 11"
          "x <= 0")
options=()
optdesc="condtermAST"


test_it "$info" $type $files $options $optdesc "$precond"

Here I have a problem, in the function test_it, if I print the value of each variable I obtain:
  precond == ("r <= 0" "x < 0"  "x < 25 || x > 30" "x <= 30 && x >= 0 || x > 35 || x < -5"
              "x < 30"
              "x <= 0"
              "x <= 11"
              "x <= 0")

So here the first element of  $precond "x > 6" disappeared, but that's not all, we also have
 optdesc=="x>6"

So I don't why there is this kind of "shift" in the arguments. It seems it comes from the "$options" array. In fact I can solve this by calling test_it with
test_it "$info" $type $files "$options" $optdesc "$precond"

Anyone has idea of why bash behaves like this?please ^^
I don't know bash semantics enough to give a reason why.

Title says Bash, shebang says sh, code says Bash, tags say both. Which is it?

Check your scripts with shellcheck and fix issues reported by it.

files is a bash array. You can't pass bash arrays as parameters to a child process. How should this work?

You can't pass arrays as arguments. You can pass the elements (strings) in an array, each as a separate argument, but if you pass the elements of more than one array it's going to be hard to tell where one array stops and the next starts, since the function just gets one big undifferentiated list of strings.

I believe the main issue with your script is the improper use of bash arrays.
Firstly, you shebang is for sh. It does not support arrays so the script should have an error about it.
Since you did not mention it, I will assume you run the script using bash command or the sh in your OS is bash.
test_it "$info" $type $files "$options" $optdesc "$precond"

In this line, the variable files, options and precond are arrays, but you expended them as regular variable. As a result, only the first value is replaced. This is the argument test_it actually receive:
test_it info2 termination tests/termination/example7.c condtermAST "x > 6"

Since options is an empty array and was expended unquoted, so no argument are passed to test_it. This might explain why an argument is at the wrong index.
Since it is difficult the provide multiple arrays to a function as arguments, I think you should change the logic of you script to move the loop outside of the function test_it. For example, something like:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test_it() {
    info="$1"
    type="$2"
    file="$3"
    optdesc="$4"
    precond="$5"

    options=("${@:6}") # all arguments after the sixth one

    filename="log/$type/$file-$optdesc.log" # typo in $file variable ?
    if [[ ! -f "$filename" ]]; then
        touch "$filename" # quote all variables to prevent word splitting!
    fi

    # it is not necessary to check if options is empty
    ./prog "$file" "${options[@]}" -precondition "${precond}" > "$filename" # quote all variables to prevent word splitting!
 }

# all variable definitions...

for i in "${!files[@]}" # move loop here
do
    test_it "$info" "$type" "${files[i]}" "$optdesc" "${precond[i]}" "${options[@]}" # options is moved the back so we can pass any number of parameters
done

An other way would be to directly access array variables in test_it without setting them from function arguments

You can use namerefs to access global arrays by name, rather than by value.
test_it() {
    info=$1
    type=$2
    declare -n files=$3
    declare -n options=$4
    optdesc=$5
    declare -n precond=$6

   for idx in "${!files[@]}"
   do          
       filename="log/$type/$filed-$optdesc.log"
       if [[ ! -f $filename ]]; then     
            touch "$filename"
       fi        
       ./prog $file "${options[@]}" -precondition  "${precond[idx]}" > "$filename"
   done
 }

type="termination"
info="info1"
files=("tests/termination/boolean.c"
       "tests/termination/cacm2009a.c"
       "tests/termination/cav2006.c"
       "tests/termination/example1.c"
       "tests/termination/example2a.c"
       "tests/termination/tacas2013a.c" )
precond=("${files[@]/*/"true"}")
options=("-ctl-cfg" "AF{exit: true}")
optdesc="termCFG"

test_it "$info" "$type" files options "$optdesc" precond

Note that you don't need to test the length of options inside test_it (though if you did, I would use (( ${#options[@]} == 0 )) instead); "${options[@]}" produces no words, not a single empty string, if the array is empty.
